# stored procedure too many arguments error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have written following stored procedure:
in which there are 2 tables arts and artist.artistId is a foreign key in arts table.

```
create procedure spInsertArts(
     @artsId int out,
     @name varchar(50),
     @category varchar(50),
     @artistId int
     )
     as
          begin
            declare @artistId int
    set @artistId=@@IDENTITY

            if exists(select artistId from artist)
              insert into arts(name,category,artistId) values(@name,@category,@artistId)
           end
```

I am getting error as:

> Procedure or function spInsertArts has too many arguments specified.

The code used to call this procedure is:

```
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox1.Text); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", DropDownList1.SelectedValue); 
SqlParameter output = new SqlParameter(); 
output.ParameterName = "@artsId"; 
output.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int; 
output.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output; 
cmd.Parameters.Add(output); 
con.Open(); 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

please help

Comment: This looks like an error generated when you call the procedure, not when you are creating it. Can you provide the code you are using to call it? Also, not really related but this line: `select @artistId=SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is pointless, you may as well just set @artistId = NULL, since you have done no inserts within the current scope.

Comment: cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category",     DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
 SqlParameter output = new SqlParameter();
        output.ParameterName = "@artsId";
        output.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
        output.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(output);
con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: i corrected that statement as:declare @artistId int
     set @artistId=@@IDENTITY
   insert into arts(Name,Category,artistId) values(@name,@category,@artistId)

Comment: You never add the parameter `@ArtistID` to the command. This does not look like the only issue though, this procedure will only ever insert if the artist table is empty, I suspect that is not intended behaviour. It will also always insert `NULL` into `arts.Artist`. `@@IDENTITY` is no better than `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` if you haven't actually performed an insert! What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: there are 2 tables arts and artist. artist first register and there will be artistId for every artist. and then artist fill arts info i.e my arts table.where artistId is a foreign key.I want that artistId to have same value as that of in the artist table.

Comment: How do you know which artist to use?

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing any value for parametere `@artistId`
Either pass a value or change procedure and set it default value null see below:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@artistId", "VALUE_HERE");
```

OR

```
create procedure spInsertArts(
     @artsId int out,
     @name varchar(50),
     @category varchar(50),
     @artistId int = null
     )
```

Comment: ok.But aristId is a foreign key in arts table and i want artistId in arts table to be set to the value of latest artistId of artist table

Answer (score 0):

```
output.ParameterName = "@artsId";
```

You are using `"@artsId"` where it should be `"@artistId"`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment that you are aiming to use the last inserted record in the artist table you want to be using either:

```
DECLARE @artistId INT = IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.Artist');
```

Or simply

```
DECLARE @artistId INT = (SELECT MAX(ArtistID) FROM dbo.Artist);

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spInsertArts
    @name       VARCHAR(50), 
    @category   VARCHAR(50), 
    @artsId     INT OUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Artist)
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @artistId INT = (SELECT MAX(ArtistID) FROM dbo.Artist);

        INSERT dbo.Arts (Name, Category, ArtistID)
        VALUES (@Name, @Category, @ArtistID);

        SET @ArtsID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    END
END
```

I have made the following changes to your code:

- Removed the redundant parameter @ArtistID and replaced it with a local variable.
- Set @ArtsID after the insert.
- [Terminated all statements with a semi-colon](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons)
- [Used the schema prefix in all object references](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)

Aaron Bertrand has done a great article called [My stored procedure "best practices" checklist](https://sqlblog.org/2008/10/30/my-stored-procedure-best-practices-checklist), which I tend to stick to, although some of it is personal preference, all of it is logical to me.

I really disagree with this logic though, it makes your procedure completely inflexible. What if you need to insert art for an artist that isn't the latest one? If inserting for the last artist is a real requirement then I'd suggest having two procedures:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spInsertArts
    @name       VARCHAR(50), 
    @category   VARCHAR(50), 
    @ArtistID   INT,
    @artsId     INT OUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT dbo.Arts (Name, Category, ArtistID)
    VALUES (@Name, @Category, @ArtistID);
END
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spInsertArtsWithLatestArtist
    @name       VARCHAR(50), 
    @category   VARCHAR(50), 
    @artsId     INT OUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @artistId INT = (SELECT MAX(ArtistID) FROM dbo.Artist);

    IF @ArtistID IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE dbo.spInsertArts @name, @category, @ArtistID, @artsID OUT;
    END
END
```